# thread_local vector segmentation fault at end of program in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, thread-local-storage

I'm trying to make a multi-threaded program but am having a weird problem with thread local vectors.  Here's the (stripped-down to only have the error) code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
thread_local std::vector<int> vec;
int main(){
    vec.push_back(3);
    std::cout << vec[0];
    // Make you push enter to show the error is at the end
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

The program compiles fine and runs mostly fine, but after I press enter I get a "program has stopped working" message.  I ran it in gdb and got this error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x004030b0 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector() ()
```

Somehow, there's an error in the vector's destructor.  Going through it with a breakpoint shows that this error happens as the program is quitting.

Making the vector not thread local makes the program work, but of course I need it to be thread local.  If I don't interact with the vector at all, the program works fine.

I'm thinking I'll have to use some alternative, but does anybody know a way to make this work?  Thanks!

EDIT: I'm stupid and forgot more info on my system.  I'm using Windows Vista 64-bit.  Running g++ -v gives me:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/MinGW/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with [edited out because it's too big and probably not relevant]
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

The thread model might actually have a lot to do with it.

Comment: how are your threads created? do you `join` the threads?

Comment: The code given in this question compiles and executes successfully, with no errors, with gcc 5.1.1

Comment: Code works for me on Linux GCC 5.1.1. What compiler/version are you using?

Comment: Bill: I'm not even making the threads yet, see the code above.  Just making the vector thread_local is what's causing the errors.

Comment: Are you compiling with the `-pthread` flag?

Comment: No, but I've been able to multithread without it (and wasn't able to multithread before getting posix).  I just tried compiling with -pthread anyway and it still didn't work..

Comment: The problem is compiler/platform dependent. It appears that thread_local storage isn't calling the destructor at the appropriate time, such that as the program shuts down, the destructor is borked. Try storing the vector with std::shared_ptr< std::vector<int> > vecptr, then explicitly reset the ptr before exit...see if that changes anything.

Comment: Try using `__thread` instead

Answer (score -1):

It is setup dependent; I have successfully compiled and run your example program on Windows 7 (64 bit) with the 64 bit MinGW. Perhaps it is related to the fact that you use the 32 bit MinGW installation on 64 bit platform? My g++ -v gives the following (same version and thread model as yours, different arch):

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```